# How do we restart levels?

Tags: entity-system

When you run out of moves, you will need to go back to the beginning of a level. If a level objective is not complete, this means you have to restart a level. And the level will simply replace all of the items back in the level. I don’t understand why we restart.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you've attempted to implement your level loading and restarting so far, and where you've gotten stuck, or what specific part you need help with. Can you edit your question to include more details?

Comment: Are you asking how to restart a level in a technical sense or why from a game design perspective restarting should be an option?

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: Are you asking how or why? And are you asking from a technical perspective or a game design perspective? It is not clear to me.